# Pyspark - transform array of string to map and then map to columns possibly using pyspark and not UDFs or other perf intensive transformations

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working on some data that has some key value headers and payload. I have managed to parse the header to the following array:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+ 
|col(header)                                                 | col(payload) |
+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
[someheader, key1, value1, key2, value2, key3, value3]       | payload      |
```

The someheader will be dropped and the remaining need to be transformed to a map as follows:

```
{
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3,
 }
```

and then I transform these key values to columns as follows (schema is known, though it would be cool to know how to do it with dynamic schema):

```
+-------------+--------+--------+-----------+
|key1         |key2    | key3   |payload    |
+-------------+--------+--------+-----------+
|value1       |value2  | value3 |payload    |
```

How can we do the array to map conversion in pyspark without python UDFs or any similar constructs that are sub optimal in perf? Also, would like to not involve pandas.

Here is what I have so far - it works but reading the spark docs, the UDFs have been known to be attributed to lower perf (and an anti-pattern of sorts):

```
# imports
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split, expr, udf, regexp_replace, lit

# udf function to convert arr to map
def to_map(arr):
    map_value = dict()
    for i in range(1,len(arr),2):
        key = arr[i]
        value = arr[i+1]
        map_value[key] = value
    return map_value

# spark session with AWS creds
spark = SparkSession\
            .builder\
            .appName("test-app")\
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "<aws access key>") \
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "<aws secret key>") \
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
            .getOrCreate()

# read the file
df = spark.read.text('s3a://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2023-50/segments/1700679099281.67/wet/CC-MAIN-20231128083443-20231128113443-00003.warc.wet.gz', lineSep="\n\r\n\r\n")

# trim whitespaces, not just spaces
df = df.select(regexp_replace(df.value, r"^\s+|\s+$", "").alias("value"))

# split string into header and payload columns
df = df.select(split(df.value, '\r\n\r\n').alias('s')) \
    .withColumn('header', expr('s[0]')) \
    .withColumn('payload', expr('s[1]')) \
    .select(col('header'), col('payload'))

# split the header into key value pair list 
# example: WARC/1.0\r\nWARC-Type: warcinfo\r\nWARC-Date: 2023-12-12T01:40:15Z\r\nWARC-Filename: CC-MAIN-20231128083443-20231128113443-00003.warc.wet.gz\r\nWARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:6082596d-524a-4e49-b1dd-86582dc01a2f>\r\nContent-Type: application/warc-fields\r\nContent-Length: 382
# becomes: [WARC/1.0, WARC-Type, warcinfo, WARC-Date, 2023-12-12T01:40:15Z, WARC-Filename, CC-MAIN-20231128083443-20231128113443-00003.warc.wet.gz, WARC-Record-ID, <urn:uuid:6082596d-524a-4e49-b1dd-86582dc01a2f>, Content-Type, application/warc-fields, Content-Length, 382]
df = df.select(split(df.header, ': |\r\n').alias('h'), col('payload'))

# create a UDF for the to_map function defined above
array_to_map = udf(to_map, MapType(StringType(),StringType()))

# convert array to map, and then map to columns using the known schema (how would one do it without a known schema?)
df = df.withColumn('header_map',array_to_map(df.h)) \
    .select(expr("header_map['WARC-Filename']").alias("warcFileName"), 
            expr("header_map['Content-Length']").cast("integer").alias("contentLength"),
            expr("to_timestamp(header_map['WARC-Date'])").alias("warcDate"),
            expr("header_map['WARC-Record-ID']").alias("warcRecordId"),
            expr("header_map['Content-Type']").alias("contentType"),
            expr("header_map['WARC-Type']").alias("warcType"),
            expr("header_map['WARC-Refers-To']").alias("warcRefersTo"),
            expr("header_map['WARC-Identified-Content-Language']").alias("language"),
            expr("header_map['WARC-Block-Digest']").alias("blockDigest"),
            expr("header_map['WARC-Target-URI']").alias("url"),
            expr("header_map['WARC-Target-URI']").alias("docId"),
            expr("header_map['WARC-Target-URI']").alias("partitionKey"),
            col('payload').alias("docText")) \
    .where(col('warcType') == lit('conversion')) \
    .drop('warcFileName')

df.show(n=5, truncate=False)
df.printSchema()
```

```
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|contentLength|warcDate           |warcRecordId                                   |contentType|warcType  |warcRefersTo                                   |language|blockDigest                          |url                                                                  |docId                                                                |partitionKey                                                         |docText          |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|27923        |2023-11-28 09:43:44|<urn:uuid:783397a2-6c03-41ac-ab5b-bd57685a0ed2>|text/plain |conversion|<urn:uuid:20764b8a-6ab0-4c23-ba54-40854a70b3af>|zho     |sha1:4XCBUNJVBXKQ63MKM2KTMGUPGC74FTSD|http://027sunflower.com/list/%E5%90%88%E5%AE%B6%E4%B8%AD%E5%AE%9DA   |http://027sunflower.com/list/%E5%90%88%E5%AE%B6%E4%B8%AD%E5%AE%9DA   |http://027sunflower.com/list/%E5%90%88%E5%AE%B6%E4%B8%AD%E5%AE%9DA   | ... <truncated> |
|23738        |2023-11-28 09:18:49|<urn:uuid:87276745-6924-46c4-bf1a-55b51cd5c9b0>|text/plain |conversion|<urn:uuid:ed65b632-8ba1-4f1a-b57c-f359cbaea9a2>|zho     |sha1:SERSYY5GWIAD2CBRTFHRYJVDFC5QBJRZ|http://0455.hk/index.asp?areaid=53                                   |http://0455.hk/index.asp?areaid=53                                   |http://0455.hk/index.asp?areaid=53                                   | ... <truncated> |
|43827        |2023-11-28 10:30:30|<urn:uuid:306608d1-bb8d-4071-83aa-388a9333791c>|text/plain |conversion|<urn:uuid:7acff67a-fd7c-4747-a269-e542af700ce3>|eng,zho |sha1:RYKE6ANAB674262OQ2VBDINQM3IXQC45|http://0554c.com/index/Article/info.html?cate=5&id=11                |http://0554c.com/index/Article/info.html?cate=5&id=11                |http://0554c.com/index/Article/info.html?cate=5&id=11                | ... <truncated> |
|1137         |2023-11-28 10:58:30|<urn:uuid:0870b29d-fc06-4a44-97ef-6876bc0fbbee>|text/plain |conversion|<urn:uuid:17042b32-0223-4589-8ceb-644a887e2776>|zho,eng |sha1:J7XVE2KML4YTJYN33VEL4SZRJSAGBKRJ|http://0571ztq.com/jiage/class/?31.html                              |http://0571ztq.com/jiage/class/?31.html                              |http://0571ztq.com/jiage/class/?31.html                              | ... <truncated> |
|1921         |2023-11-28 10:41:49|<urn:uuid:f95cd1dd-3bf8-4272-9f3b-10f847d543e6>|text/plain |conversion|<urn:uuid:fb642dce-08c9-4b41-bc93-13907080b95d>|deu,eng |sha1:IWDUDKUJVRYILJZ4UIHGADV2FFB3JCPS|http://06.live-radsport.ch/index.php?src=email&id=225657&type=details|http://06.live-radsport.ch/index.php?src=email&id=225657&type=details|http://06.live-radsport.ch/index.php?src=email&id=225657&type=details| ... <truncated> |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
only showing top 5 rows

root
 |-- contentLength: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- warcDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- warcRecordId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contentType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- warcType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- warcRefersTo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- language: string (nullable = true)
 |-- blockDigest: string (nullable = true)
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- docId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partitionKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- docText: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed avoid to use UDFs by using a few of the functions in `pyspark.sql.functions`.

Let's first create you dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (
            ["someheader", "key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", "key3", "value3"],
            "payload",
        ),
    ],
    ["header", "payload"],
)
```

Then, we calculate the output:

```py
# Calculating the array column's length to be able to extract the keys and
# values later on
array_length = (
    df.withColumn("array_length", F.size("header"))
    .agg(F.first("array_length"))
    .collect()[0][0]
)

output = (
    df.select(
        F.explode(
            F.map_from_arrays(
                F.array([F.col("header")[i] for i in range(1, array_length, 2)]),
                F.array([F.col("header")[i] for i in range(2, array_length, 2)]),
            )
        ),
        "payload",
    )
    .groupBy("payload")
    .pivot("key")
    .agg(F.first("value"))
)

>>> output.show()
+-------+------+------+------+
|payload|  key1|  key2|  key3|
+-------+------+------+------+
|payload|value1|value2|value3|
+-------+------+------+------+
```

The idea is the following:

- we extract the keys and values by indexing in the original array column (uneven indices are keys, even indices are values)
- then we transform those 2 columns into 1 map column
- after that, we explode those values to multiple columns

Then you can simply groupBy and pivot to get your wanted dataframe.

**NOTE**: this can handle any length/name of keys dynamically, but cannot handle the situation where your original `header` column would have different length arrays in 1 dataframe